# fasterxml jackson databind upgrade to 2.15.2

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, fasterxml, jackson2

I am trying to upgrade our fasterxml jackson databind from version 2.9.3 to 2.15.2.

But i am getting following runtime error, Build was successful.

Springboot version - 2.2.6

Article i used for reference : https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-dependency-issue-in-spring-boot-with-maven

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.findConstructorBindingAnnotatedConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.getBindConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:48) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.forType(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.cisco.cres.CresServiceApplication.main(CresServiceApplication.java:13) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    ... 24 more
```

Pom.xml

Initial :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My Change:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can someone tell why exactly its happening and solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot manages jackson dependencies & for some cases relies on them (which is why you get that error)

You can check which boot brings which version here, for instance for 2.7.X, 3.0.X and 3.1.X (all the still supported versions from pivotal)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.16/reference/html/dependency-versions.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.4/reference/html/dependency-versions.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/dependency-versions.html

There you can see that 3.1.X brings jackson 2.15.X by default.

You should, at the very least, upgrade to the latest 2.X version (2.7.16) and see if you then can manually upgrade to jackson 2.15.2

2.2.X is EOL since 2020-10-16 (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support)

Comment: we cant upgrade spring boot right now due to some constraints.

Comment: can we still possibly do this jackson databind upgrade, by changing/upgrading some dependences.

Comment: it is spring-boot itself failing, so that boot version cannot work with that jackson version

try to lower the jackson-versions or bump the boot versions. That's all the reasonable options I see here

Comment: it seems that the missing class, JsonProcessingException, is missing since 2.15

it still exists with 2.14, so you could try to go to at least 2.14 and see if that works for you.


see 

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html
and 

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.15/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html wherer it is not ound